# Error 1064 Django inspectdb

Tags: python, mysql, django

When I execute `python manage.py inspectdb` I get this error:

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TABLES' at line 1")

Scenario:

- mysql version 4.1.22
- python version 2.7.6
- Django version 1.9.2
- MySQL-python-1.2.4b4 using `python setup.py build` and `sudo python setup.py install`.

This is how the part od databases in my Django settings.py file looks like:

```
DATABASES = {
   'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
       'NAME': 'dbXXXXXXX',
       'USER': 'centr',
       'PASSWORD': '****',
       'HOST': '192.168.5.225',
       'PORT': '3306',
   }
}
```

Here is the full traceback:

```
# This is an auto-generated Django model module.
# You'll have to do the following manually to clean this up:
#   * Rearrange models' order
#   * Make sure each model has one field with primary_key=True
#   * Make sure each ForeignKey has `on_delete` set to the desired behavior.
#   * Remove `managed = False` lines if you wish to allow Django to create, modify, and delete the table
# Feel free to rename the models, but don't rename db_table values or field names.
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/inspectdb.py", line 25, in handle
    for line in self.handle_inspection(options):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/inspectdb.py", line 53, in handle_inspection
    for table_name in connection.introspection.table_names(cursor):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/introspection.py", line 58, in table_names
    return get_names(cursor)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/introspection.py", line 53, in get_names
    return sorted(ti.name for ti in self.get_table_list(cursor)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/introspection.py", line 49, in get_table_list
    cursor.execute("SHOW FULL TABLES")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 112, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TABLES' at line 1")
```

What am I doing wrong and what can I do to solve this problem and create my models from database schema in Django?

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ProgrammingError: 1064 while executing inspectdb with django and mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58285818/programmingerror-1064-while-executing-inspectdb-with-django-and-mysql-database)